# How do I update comments in real time for this Laravel 8 blogging app?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have made a blogging application in Laravel 8.

The articles support comments and comment replies. I am currently working on the *update comments* functionality.

In the Comment model, I "merge" comments and replies like so:

```
public function replies() {
  return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

In the controller, I have:

```
public function update_comment(Request $request, $id) {
    $comment = Comment::find($id);

    if ($comment->user_id === auth()->user()->id) {
      $comment->body = $request->get('msg');
      $comment->save();
      
      if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
          'status'    => 'success',
          'message'   => 'The comment was updated.'
        ]);
      } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'The comment was updated.');
      }
      
    } 
}
```

The application supports themes, so the above code has to work with or without AJAX. And it does.

In `comments-list.blade.php` I have:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    @if (null == $comment->parent_id)
        <li class="depth-1 comment">
            <div class="comment__avatar">
                <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $comment->user->avatar) }}"
                    alt="{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="comment__content">
                <div class="comment__info">
                    <div class="comment__author">{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}</div>
                    <div class="comment__meta">
                        <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</div>
                        @auth
                            <div class="comment__reply">
                                @if ($comment->user->id !== Auth::user()->id)
                                    <a class="comment-reply-link" href="#0">
                                        <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Reply
                                    </a>
                                @endif

                                @if ($comment->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                                    <a href="#0" class="comment-edit-link">
                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                                    </a>
                                    @include(
                                        'themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-delete-form',
                                        ['commentOrReply' => $comment]
                                    )
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        @endauth
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="comment__text">
                    <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            @auth
                @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-form')

                @if ($comment->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                    @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form', [
                        'commentOrReply' => $comment,
                    ])
                @endif
            @endauth

            {{-- Comment replies --}}
            @if (count($comment->replies))
                <ul class="children">
                    @foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)
                        <li class="depth-2 comment">
                            <div class="comment__avatar">
                                <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $reply->user->avatar) }}"
                                    alt="{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}"
                                    width="50" height="50">
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment__content">
                                <div class="comment__info">
                                    <div class="comment__author">{{ $reply->user->first_name }}
                                        {{ $reply->user->last_name }}</div>
                                    <div class="comment__meta">
                                        <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($reply->created_at)) }}
                                        </div>
                                        @auth
                                            <div class="comment__reply">
                                                @if ($reply->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                                                    <a href="#0" class="comment-edit-link">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                                                    </a>
                                                    @include(
                                                        'themes/' .
                                                            $theme_directory .
                                                            '/partials/comment-delete-form',
                                                        ['commentOrReply' => $reply]
                                                    )
                                                @endif
                                            </div>
                                        @endauth
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment__text">
                                    <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            @auth
                                @if ($reply->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                                    @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form', [
                                        'commentOrReply' => $reply,
                                    ])
                                @endif
                            @endauth
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I use the same template for editing *comments& and *comment replies*:

```
<div class="h-text-center alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--success">
    The comment was updated. Refresh the page to see the changes.
</div>

  <form class="commentEditForm" method="post" action="{{ route('comment.update', $commentOrReply->id) }}" autocomplete="off" novalidate> 
    @csrf
      <fieldset>
        <div class="message form-field">
          <textarea name="msg" id="message" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message" required>{{ $commentOrReply->body }}</textarea>

          @error('msg')
          <p class="help-block text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>
        <br>
        <input name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-wide btn--large h-full-width" value="Update Comment" type="submit">
      </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

I use the following code to update (and add) comments and comment replies:

```
// Add/Edit comment 
$(document).on('submit', '.commentForm, .commentEditForm', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    form.validate({
      errorElement: "p",
      errorClass: "help-block text-danger",
      rules: {
        msg: "required",
      },
      messages: {
        msg: "Enter a comment",
      }
    });

    // Check if the form is valid
    if (!form.valid()) {
      return;
    }

    var $fields = form.find("textarea"),
      url = form.attr("action"),
      data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "post",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'success') {
          form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
            .slideDown(250)
            .delay(2500)
            .slideUp(250);
            $fields.val("");

            if (form.hasClass('commentEditForm')) {
              form.slideUp();
              form.closest(".depth-1").find(".comment__text").slideDown();
            }

        } else {
          form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
            .slideDown(250)
            .delay(2500)
            .slideUp(250);
        }
      },
      error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      },
    });
});
```

#### The goal

My goal is to make it so that the comment (or reply) update is immediately visible on the page, *without* refreshing the page.

So, I need to get the newly edited comment and display it on the page.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: mmmm WebSocket?

Comment: have you considered ajax polling?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam The theme is made pf a pretty old HTML theme that uses jQuery. :(

Comment: Not certain. Check laravel pusher and Echo. This supports old version I guess

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes, but it updates with the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the ajax call to update the comment in the database you are only returning a status success so, clearly, nothing happens in your html page.

You have to add the following steps:

-1-return the updated comment body from the controller

-2-in the success part of your $.ajax you get the comment and update the content (it looks like you are not using id='comment-id' or something similar in your html but you need to know where to update the comment)

The first step below:

```
public function update_comment(Request $request, $id) {
    $comment = Comment::find($id);
    //you may add validation here
    if ($comment->user_id === auth()->user()->id) {
      $comment->body = $request->get('msg');
      $comment->save();
  
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
      return response()->json([
        'status'    => 'success',
        'message'   => 'The comment was updated.'
        //updated comment here
        'body'=>$request->get('msg');
      ]);
    } else {
     return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'The comment was updated.');
  }
  
 } 
}
```

The second part below only shows where to update in the comment:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  type: "post",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  success: function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'success') {
      form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
        .slideDown(250)
        .delay(2500)
        .slideUp(250);
        $fields.val("");

        if (form.hasClass('commentEditForm')) {
          form.slideUp();
          form.closest(".depth-1").find(".comment__text").text(response.body).slideDown();
        }

    } else {
     //...
     //...
```